Возвращается ошибка 87 - не верный параметр
Мне нужно получить номер сектора в котором хранится содержимое файла.
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <iostream>

    int main() {
    
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
        L"I:\\Pond.txt",               // Путь к файлу
        GENERIC_READ,                         // Режим доступа для чтения
        FILE_SHARE_READ,                      // Режим совместного доступа (для чтения)
        NULL,                                 // Атрибуты безопасности (по умолчанию)
        OPEN_EXISTING,                        // Открывать только существующий файл
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,                // Атрибуты файла (обычный файл)
        NULL                                  // Хэндл шаблона файла (не используется)
    );



    //BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION fileInfo;
    //FILE_FULL_DIR_INFO fileInfo;
    //FILE_ID_INFO fileInfo;                          //FileIdInfo
    _FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO fileInfo;                  //FileIdBothDirectoryInfo 


    if (GetFileInformationByHandleEx(hFile, FileIdBothDirectoryInfo, &fileInfo,
                                     sizeof(_FILE_ID_BOTH_DIR_INFO)))
    {
        DWORD index = fileInfo.FileIndex;

    }
    else std::cout<< GetLastError();
     
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return 0;    
}

Сверил с документацией - всё нормально, но возвращает INVALID PARAMETER. В чём дело?

Давайте посмотрим описание флага...

FileIdBothDirectoryInfo
Файлы в указанном каталоге должны быть извлечены. Используется для дескрипторов каталога.

Видите это — Используется для дескрипторов каталога. А у вас дескриптор чего? Вот и получается — неверный, неприменимый параметр...

ё-моё... А как тогда мне быть с файлом? Как мне получить адрес (сектор) с содержимым файла?

Чтобы получить физ.сектор, который занимает файл на диске, нужно использовать DeviceIoControl() с кодом FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS.
